# wordpress - sharing private content in whatsapp link is not displaying properly

Tags: wordpress

I am using a plugin WP Private Content Plus for blog visibility, which means some blogs are only available for members(registered users) only, I am giving login page URL as a redirection URL for those who are not registered.

My problem is when I am sharing the normal blogs in WhatsApp the link is working perfectly, which means featured image of the blog and title displaying. but when I am sharing the members-only blogs through WhatsApp it is displaying login page URL which we gave in the plugin. how can I keep the featured image and title of the blog even its members-only blog?. Thank you.

Comment: You can't normally display hidden content (seen only by the loged in your website) in any external sns like Whatsapp. there I can think of to make it seen, is to create a normal blog link (dont need being member) that have some minor details (title, image ...) basically what you want to be seen when you include the link in whatsapp, and in which you make a redirection to the members only blog link. There are some other ways but it need some php programming skills.